# NSUserDefaults in iOS10 not working on device

Tags: ios10

My app uses NSUserDefaults and it is running as expected in the simulator on Xcode 8 with an iOS10 option selected.

I have an old iPhone 5 I use for testing and I have upgraded this to the iOS10 GM and my NSUserDefaults are not working.

The app does not crash but it just does not save any information when I set an NSUserDefault.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe the device storage runs out.

Comment: please explain how it is not working? can't save, load get nil??

Comment: Nothing is getting saved, I don't understand how it can be working in the simulator and not on the device.

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry I have found the problem, it is with my UISwitch**

All of the NSUserDefault code is working fine.

The switch was what set the UserDefault and I have found that if you slide the switch it does not register but if you tap the switch it does.

I have found that this bug started in iOS 7 so when I updated my app for iOS 10 and the Development Target moved up to iOS 8 the bug started.

So in the simulator the switch responded to a tap but on the device if I slide my finger across the switch it didn't register even though the switch changed state.

Thanks for the suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 0):

in Xcode 8 / iOS10, NSUserDefaults is now UserDefaults, and standardUserDefaults() is now standard() - Try updating your code to this new name scheme and see if that fixes it.

Here is the Apple documentation on the dropping of the NS prefix: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0086-drop-foundation-ns.md